# For electron, Making a transparent windows but I can't click its edge

Tags: electron

When I use transparent Windows, an area 5px from the windows edge cannot respond to DOM events.

```
let captureWin = new BrowserWindow({
    fullscreen: os.platform() === 'win32' || undefined,
    width: display.bounds.width,
    height: display.bounds.height,
    x: display.bounds.x,
    y: display.bounds.y,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    // skipTaskbar: true,
    // autoHideMenuBar: true,
    movable: false,
    resizable: false,
    enableLargerThanScreen: true,
    hasShadow: false,
})
captureWin.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver')
captureWin.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true)
captureWin.setFullScreenable(false)
captureWin.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'capture.html'))
```

In the screenshot window, run:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    console.log([e.x, e.y])
})
```

When the mouse moves within 5px of the window edge, the console does not print out the mouse position.

Comment: Hello, do you mind adding a screenshot as well?

Comment: Thanks, I suspect it's the frame you're clicking but it's transparent but since I don't have any proof I won't post a answer